# how to bake all things together and make render fast

Tags: rendering

for example, I have a room with several things inside, I switch to render view and when move mouse (to change view) it renders again which cause it very slow.
I do not want to bake every thing one by one. is there a way I can bake all at a time, and how to make it use the bake result (texture or uv map, don't know) to make render fast? (that is, only use bake result, do not calculate or calculate as little as possible).
key point is, do not want to set it one by one (there are many things in the room)

example

1. here is the first snapshot of the simple duplicate of this problem, there are two objects with material of different colors
2. here is the second snapshot, when in render view, move mouse to change view point, it will be noisy, in this simple case it is not slow, but if many objects, it will be slow, the render engine eevee is faster than cycles but still slow
3. then I baked two objects together with all default setting, into one uvmap image named "bake", in this step, I have to create a new uvmap all called "bake" for each object, is there a way I can set it together, not one by one?
4. then I have to assign the bake uvmap to each object for render view, in the attached picture it is marked as 1 and 2, if there are many objects, this will be trouble, is there a way to do it together in a time?
   last problem is that there is small problem at last, see mark 3. how to improve it?

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]
[image: step 4]

Comment: it depends on a lot of things. Yes, by baking you can make it quicker. But also by hiding things. Or less subdividing ...or....or...or. Please show us your blend file or at least some screenshots what you did with settings.

Comment: Search for Atlas texture ... Here used with SIMPLE Bake addon make it easier ... https://youtu.be/TpXPMuBKSEA

Comment: ad 3 - it is just overlapping island margin ... when Unwrap (with Smart UV) increase value for Island Margin or lower value in Bake > Output > Margin. Just a note unwrap value is not in px since it can be later any image dimension. Does link to video solved your problem?

Comment: have tried the tool in the video. it says it should have "multiple objects to one texture", but I do not have this feature in version 6.4.0

Comment: also, after bake, I have not found the way to make the baked uvmap take effect instead of the original uvmap.